# Qt и Python: две radioButton = str значение переменной

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtextedit, qradiobutton

**`ui`** - ссылка на графическое окно, есть две `radioButton`. 
Надо передать значение в переменную и вывести переменную в `textEdit`.

```
ui.radioButton(variable=var, value=0)
ui.radioButton_2(variable=var, value=1)


def clk():
    if var.get() == 0:
        ui.textEdit.setText('.')

    elif var.get() == 1:
        ui.textEdit.setText(',')
```

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: не работает этот кусок)

Comment: Traceback покажите

Comment: А var что это? ?

Comment: И вообще надо привести минимально воспроизводимый пример)

Comment: можно без var - я через var пытался передать переключение radiobutton

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96262/discussion-between--and-aleksandr-chirikov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit,
                             QButtonGroup, QApplication, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        attrs            = ['.', ',']
        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()

        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.radioButton = QRadioButton('{}'.format(attrs[0]))
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton)

        self.radioButton_2 = QRadioButton('{}'.format(attrs[1]))
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton_2)    

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)        


    def check_button(self, radioButton):
#        print("radioButton-> `{}`".format(radioButton.text()))
        self.textEdit.setText(radioButton.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лихо вы накидали)

Comment: спасибо) сейчас буду интегрировать))

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov удачи вам.